# how to make background in all screen for all ios devices?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I created Sprite Sheet with SpriteHelper. When I created a background in spritehelper, the picture size was 1920 x 1280. How to make background  for all device in all screen.

```
  CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

  CCSpriteBatchNode *sprites_for_game;      
  sprites_for_game = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprite_UntitledSheet.png"];

  [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprite_UntitledSheet.plist"];
   [self addChild:sprites_for_game];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"background"];
        sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        [sprites_for_game addChild:sprite];
```

iphone petina 3.5 inch
http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_9096412_10672667.png

iphone petina 4.0 inch
http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_8101239_10672678.png

Comment: ipad  http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_6722907_10672708.png

ipad petina  http://pixs.ru/showimage/Snimokekra_7539276_10672720.png  please help me

Comment: are you set Launch images for all devices correctly?

Comment: i think so. i created universal app in spriteHelper.